# QString::toStdString() produces gibberish on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, unicode, character-encoding

I build a 32bit app in Debug mode, linking against Qt 32bit Release DLLs.

I get terrific gibberish when I use `QString::toStdString()` -- lots of text like `M i c r o s o f t . W i n d o w s . S y s t e m C o m p a t i b l e`:

```cpp
#define APPS_FULL_VERSION_STR "3.1.0"
...
const char* argv[] = {"./program", nullptr};
int argc = sizeof(argv) / sizeof(argv[0]) - 1;
QApplication app(argc, const_cast<char**>(argv));
application.setApplicationVersion(APPS_FULL_VERSION_STR);

std::cout << app.applicationVersion().toStdString() << std::endl;
// outputs gibberish

std::cout << app.applicationVersion().toUtf8().toStdString() << std::endl;
// outputs gibberish

std::cout << app.applicationVersion().toUtf8().constData() << std::endl;
// outputs 3.1.0

auto bytes = app.applicationVersion().toUtf8();
std::cout << std::string{bytes.constData(), (unsigned) bytes.length() } << std::endl;
// outputs 3.1.0
```

But that's strange, as [here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/include/qt/QtCore/qstring.h.html) one might see that:

```cpp
inline std::string QString::toStdString() const
{ return toUtf8().toStdString(); }

inline std::string QByteArray::toStdString() const
{ return std::string(constData(), length()); }
```

What's wrong? And what is the corect way to convert a `QString` to `std::string` in a way that would work both on Linux and Windows?

Interestingly, in other places of my code where I use `toStdString()`, I don't get the problem. It's only with `QApplication::applicationVersion()`.

Also, when building in Release mode, I don't have such a problem.

Comment: How do you link Qt? You must not mix debug Qt dlls with release executable and vice versa. Use a proper build system like qmake or cmake instead hand-made vs solutions.

Comment: @chehrlic, Could you please, eleborate on why I cannot mix my debug code with release dlls? Is it for all libararies on Windows or is it only for Qt? Just normally in other projects on linux I mixed this quite freely and had no problems.

Comment: @chehrlic Btw, what about RelWithDebInfo? Which version of Qt should Iuse for such a build of my project? I use cmake.

Comment: @chehrlic And also. If I fixed the one test with `.toUtf8().constData()` and everything else works fine, is it okay to use Release Qt dlls with my Debug build after all?

Comment: Blame MS - the debug libs use the msvcrt debug runtime, the release ones the msvcrt release runtime - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library?view=msvc-170 . You must not mix them.

Comment: @chehrlic Thank you! You mean that Qt uses /MT or /MD for release and /MTd or /MDd for debug build. And you mean that this should conflict with what my project uses? But I have just chcked that my project is compiled with /MT in debug mode (I checked that it was really debug by manually checking NDEBUG -- defined in release and not defined in debug indeed). So it looks like it should not conflict. Btw, why cmake does not use /MTd for debug build of my project?

Comment: I don't know what you've installed nor which flags you use. Normally cmake does the correct things when all libs (debug and release) are properly installed. Looks like you messed around with your compiler flags. Compiling with /MT in debug mode when you link against debug Qt libs will for sure not work as already said and explained above.